# Cascade Delete in Gorm does not remove Associated Tables

Tags: go-gorm

Im new to Gorm. Im trying to do a cascade delete whereby if I delete a User, the Role (Belongs To), Profile (Has One) and Books (One-to-Many) which are associated with the User will be deleted as well.

I set up my model below but cascading can't seem to work. When I delete my User, the Role, Profile and Books still remain in the database rather than being deleted / soft deleted.

Can someone point me to where I did wrong? Thanks

**User Model**

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age uint    `json:"age"`
    Profile Profile `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    RoleID int `json:"role_id"`
    Role Role `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Books []Book `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Book struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title string `json:"title"`
    UserID uint `json:"user_id"`
}

type Profile struct {
    gorm.Model
    Country string `json:"country"`
    UserID uint `json:"user_id"`
}

type Role struct {
    ID int
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `gorm.Model`, or more specifically when your model has a field of type `gorm.DeletedAt`, GORM uses [soft delete](https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Soft-Delete). That is, records do not actually get deleted, only the aforementioned field gets updated, and the records are normally excluded from query results. Consequently, cascade delete will not trigger.

You can find, and then *actually* delete, soft-deleted objects using the [`Unscoped`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Unscoped) method. Alternatively, change your models so that they are not affected by soft-deletion.

Comment: I notice the cascade Delete for Role does not take effect when User is deleted, unlike Profile and Books. Thinking through, that is fine since it makes sense for the role to still exist. However, why would that be such an option for Cascade Delete for Belong-To Association when it does not seem to work at all? or is it working but in a different way?

Comment: It does work. If you delete a Role, all Users belonging to it will be deleted. Take a look at the table schema created by GORM, the foreign key constraint for Role is on the User table.