# On delete cascade not working as intended in Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

So I am very new to `Gorm` and am playing around with it but I can't seem to get on delete cascade to work. These are my models:

```
type Base struct {
    Id string `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}

type User struct {
    Base
    Role     string  `json:"role"`
    Username string  `json:"username" gorm:"unique"`
    Password string  `json:"password"`
    Profile  Profile `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Profile struct {
    Base
    UserId string `json:"user_id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Bio    string `json:"bio" gorm:"default:hello world!"`
    Age    uint8  `json:"age"`
}
```

**The problem is, when I perform a delete operation on a user object, it gets deleted properly but it's associated `Profile` object isn't deleted. I know that `Gorm` has a soft delete functionality but I don't have a `gorm.DeletedAt` field in my `Base` model. My `User` and `Profile` model also share the same `Base` so they should behave similarly in terms of the delete.**

Here's how I am running the delete:

```
...
id := "my-uuid" // this would be a real value. this is just an example
Database.Where("id = ?", id).Delete(&models.User{})
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

**Edit:**
I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749708/cascade-delete-in-gorm-does-not-remove-associated-tables#:%7E:text=DeletedAt%20%2C%20GORM%20uses%20soft%20delete,objects%20using%20the%20Unscoped%20method.) and have tried following it but I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: from gorm repo: [gorm delete](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/8c3018b96aea241a35b769291de6edd2a3378b44/tests/delete_test.go#L139)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using gorm v2, you can try deleting the main object, its relation, and the associated objects by using [delete with select](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-with-Select). It should be something like this:

```
Database.Select("Profile").Delete(&models.User{ID: id})
```

Comment: Awesome. This solution worked, thank you. However there was a slight tweak I had to make: `Database.Select(clause.Associations, "Profile").Delete(&models.User{Base: models.Base{Id: id}})`

Answer (score 0):

you could use **foreign key** if your database support foreign key, if not you need use **transaction** to deleted the user and profile object.

> https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html