# Does the CASCADE constraint work with a HasMany model?

Tags: go-gorm, has-many, cascading-deletes

I have a function that deletes an entry based on the URI sent to its API:

```golang
type BaseModel struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
} // there is no DeletedAt, so no soft deletes (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749708/cascade-delete-in-gorm-does-not-remove-associated-tables for a similar question)

type Person struct {
    BaseModel
    Timezone            string `gorm:"default:Etc/UTC"`
    Name                string
    ConfLoadFromBrowser bool
    ConfLoadFromDb      bool
    Pills               []Pill `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Pill struct {
    BaseModel
    PersonID   string
    Name       string
    Amount     int
    Posologies []Posology
}

func deletePerson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    personId := chi.URLParam(r, "personId")
    db.Delete(&Person{}, "id = ?", personId)
    // removed checks of successful delete and HTTP responses for simplicityt
}
```

When requesting for instance `DELETE /people/3fe88a09-afaf-4a36-95ae-af822add7103`, the relevant entry in the table `people` (`Person` in go → table `people` in SQLite) is deleted as expected (I see the record disappearing in the SQLite db), but **entries in the table `pills` that link to it are not**.

Is there a specific way to trigger a CASCADE DELETE in such HasMany model?